# Why is the CSS height:100vh; rule exceeding the viewport height on mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile, viewport-units

In order to make my header fit with all the viewports, I'm using the classic CSS rule `height: 100vh;` and it works like a charm… except on my mobile.

Actually, on the bottom of the screen the header is taller than the viewport (20px or 30px more than it should do). Because of this issue, some of the content at the bottom of the header is the hidden on mobile devices.

I've tried to fix the bug with the Chrome DevTools Console, but everything is fine when I'm using the mobile view (with all the devices).

It seems the issue comes from the browser's address bar on my mobile (I'm using Chrome).

What am I missing ? How to fix it properly ?

Here you have the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>Lorem ipsum</header>
    <main>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here the CSS :

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/** RESET CSS **/
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main{display:block;}

*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;list-style:none;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}

header{
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: Add css `html, body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: I added it, but it doesn't change anything (and inside the RESET you already have this rule `* { margin: 0; }` ).

Comment: The specificity (the priority) of `*` is less then a normal tag such as `<body>` so if a browser defaults to a certain margin, the `*` will not reset this. If you set the header to 100vh then the main section will sit below the header.

Comment: Ok, I dit it but it doesn't change anything. I think the issue comes from the Chrome browser's address bar.

Comment: [Full screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) might be relevant?

Comment: As an alternative `html, body, body > header { height: 100%; margin: 0; }` because 100vh is a calculated absolute value and 100% looks at the space that is available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using `vh` units try CSS rule `height: 100dvh`  this is dynamic viewport height and the size will be automatically adjusted in response to the mobile browsers UI state i.e. if the browser address bar is visible or not.
It is well supported in current version browsers (July 2023).

Answer (score 0):

(The answer comes from the comment section of this question.)

The CSS rule `height: 100vh;` is making any box filling all the space of the viewport, which is exactly what we are asking to her.

Things become wrong when, on **Safari or Chrome browsers for mobile**, the browser's address bar is adding an extra space : apparently, this is not a bug but an [intentional feature](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832#c5).

To solve this problem, instead of using `header { height: 100vh; }`, one can use html, `html, body, body > header { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }`.

The box is now filling all the available height and is not adding any extra space : the browser's address bar height is not added to the box.

The CSS rule `height: 100%;` has to be set for the parents (html and body) and using `margin: 0; padding: 0;` is necessary, otherwise an extra space will appear.

Here is the CSS updated and corrected :

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/** RESET CSS **/
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main{display:block;}

*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;list-style:none;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}

html,
body,
body > header{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header{
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  background: green;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```